# How do I define a function having 2 parameters, with one being a Tkinter 'event' parameter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, parameters, arguments

I am writing a program that reads a list of words from a particular text file based on the user choice.

Then this list of words is to be used as an argument for another function 'startgame()' which is also the 'event' for my Tkinter window, which is to display the words fetched from the file based on the user's choice.

However, the problem here is that when a function is a Tkinter event, there can be only this one parameter and I am unable to use the fetched words as an argument due to this.

Here's a minimum reproducible example for reference -

```
    window = Tk()

    def func1():
        fh = open("file.txt")
        reader = fh.read()
        fetched_words = reader.split('|')
        window.bind('<Return>', func2)

    def func2(event):   # here I need to add another parameter 
        word_display.configure(text=fetched_words[0])  # must have argument 'words' instead of 'fetched_words'
```

I have tried multiple methods to fix this bug, bu have been unsuccessful so far. Please help me out !

Comment: provide a [mcve] please

Comment: I have edited my question and tried my best to explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
window = Tk()

def func1():
    fh = open("file.txt")
    reader = fh.read()
    fetched_words = reader.split('|')
    window.bind('<Return>', lambda event: func2(event, fetched_words))

def func2(event, fetched_words):   # here I need to add another parameter 
    word_display.configure(text=fetched_words[0])  # must have argument 'words' instead of 'fetched_words'
```

By using lambda you can add extra parameters to a binding.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your  solution, I have been stuck on this problem for weeks ! It works perfectly now !

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept this answer if you found it helpful